# python fitz page.add_highlight_annot(start=pointa, stop=pointb) not working

Tags: python, pymupdf

i'm trying to highlight a text in a pdf from a start word "pointa" to an end word "pointb" but it wont work it will mark all the text on the page Maybe some one could help me (pleas) and figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
import fitz
import config
class FindTextblock:

        doc = fitz.open(config.fpath_int+"/test_saurce.pdf")
        for page in doc:
            wordlist = page.get_text("words")
            wordlist.sort(key=lambda w: (w[1], w[0]))  # sort vertical, then horizontal
            pointa = None
            pointb = None
            for w in wordlist:
                if w[4] == "Therapievorschlag":  # choose a word to start marking
                    pointa = fitz.Point(w[:2])  # top left of work rectangle
                    break
            for w in wordlist:
                if w[4] == "EU-Verordnung":  # some word for stopping the marking
                    pointb = fitz.Point(w[2:4])  # bottom right of word rectangle
                    break

            page.add_highlight_annot(start=pointa, stop=pointb)

        doc.save("test.pdf")

FindTextblock()
```

Thx

I have tryed everythink but i run out of ideas what could be false.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a post in the Discussions tab: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions including an example file.
Your code looks ok so far, so some more research is required.

Just made this example using top-left of "JEDE" and bottom-right of "(rechts)."
[image]

Comment: For the records: the user received an answer / solution here: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/2168